# How can i load a class that is not found when reading object from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

How can i load a class that is not found when reading object from ObjectInputStream

Example

```
    InputStream pis = new InputStream();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(pis);
    Object o = null;
    try{
        o = ois.readObject();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
       //How to try to load a class to read object again?????
       o = ois.readObject();
    }
```

Thanks,
TH

Comment: Where are you planning to load the classes from?

Comment: I just think. I plan to load the class from a new class to by pass ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

The classes of the objects you try to deserialize should already be on your classpath when trying to deserialize objects.

If you encounter this, I guess you can't really do much at runtime. Instead you can use this to detect if you are still missing classes from your classpath, and add those to your project and classpath during developing.

Comment: Well, technically you could create a custom classloader to load classes from outside the classpath.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, of course, but that would require to analyze the class name that is missing and you would have to know where to load it from. In general, this is not convenient. Where would you load this class from: `"com.expekertia.tools.CacheLoader"`?

Comment: You would indeed have to know where to load it from. About it being convenient or not, I guess that would depend on the situation. Sometimes you don't have much of a choice.

Comment: Yes, i know where to load it from. But i don't know how to load it to pass ClassNotFoundException to readObject

Answer (score 0):

Use an `RMIClassLoader` at both ends, and pay attention to its documented requirements at the sending end.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassNotFoundException` could also be thrown if the class has moved.

Let's say you serialize a class instance. Later, the class is moved, due to some refactoring. Then you are stuck as the old class fully qualified name is not longer valid. No way to get your object back from the stream.